# Using MySQL with PHP on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

How do I upload my MySQL DB to Heroku for use with a PHP app?  The only docs I found on Heroku are this:

**Using ClearDB with PHP**

Connecting to ClearDB from PHP is super easy, and merely requires the parsing of the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL to get connected, like this:

```
<?php
  $url=parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

  $server = $url["host"];
  $username = $url["user"];
  $password = $url["pass"];
  $db = substr($url["path"],1);

  mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

  mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```

I don't understand how to fill the ClearDB with my data without an SSH connection, or how to create a database or how to connect to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From  [ClearDB's Developer Center FAQ:](http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq)

> For importing data into your MySQL database, we recommend that you use both the mysql command line client as well as the mysqldump database backup utility.

Assuming you have the connection information available, use the `mysql` and `mysqldump` utilities on your local machine to connect directly to ClearDB remotely and import the data. This other SO answer may help: [How to copy a Database from one server to another server in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972453/how-to-copy-a-database-from-one-server-to-another-server-in-php/2972492#2972492)

You can export a database dump with `mysql_dump` locally, and then given the username/password/host information from `heroku config`, you can use they `mysql` utility locally to import to the remote host, so something like this:

```
$ mysqldump --user=db1user --password=db1pass local_database > db.sql  
$ mysql --host=remote_host --user=db2user --password=db2pass myschema < db.sql
```

Comment: ok, but it doesn't tell me how to connect to the Heroku DB.  The method I know is to SSH to my web host and use mysql and mysqldump.  I don't know how to do that with Heroku.

Comment: I expanded my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction. You're bypassing Heroku here

Comment: You do not need to use SSH in this case because your ClearDB database is accessible from your own computer directly over the internet, not restricted to localhost.

Comment: how do I get the value for remote_host(is it with heroku config?) and how do I set the values for db2user and db2pass?

Comment: All of these values are in the the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` config var, that should have been automatically added to your application when you added the ClearDB add-on. `$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`  The format is username:password@host

Comment: Thanks a lot @ctshryock.  I have no idea where I was supposed to find this information.