# How to make connection to heroku mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, heroku, deployment

I created a web app that I was able to successfully deploy to heroku. The site uses a mysql database that I dumped into the project directory for the app. I followed the instructions from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947506/using-mysql-with-php-on-heroku) as well as other online sources.  I entered the following command into the terminal:

```
 heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
```

and got the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://be4beb15e4506b:f601032d@us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net/heroku_e665c17e181f638?reconnect=true

Before deploying the app I then entered:

```
 mysql -u be4beb15e4506b  -h us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net -p heroku_e665c17e181f638 < /var/www/html/Clubhub.sql
```

Inside of the actual files, I added the following code for the database connection:

```
url = parse_url(getenv(" mysql://be4beb15e4506b:f601032d@us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net/heroku_e665c17e181f638?reconnect=true"));
$server = $url["us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net"];
$username = $url["be4beb15e4506b"];
$password = $url["heroku_e665c17e181f638"];
$db = substr($url["/var/www/html/Clubhub.sql"], 1);
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);
```

For some reason whenever I navigate to a page where a query is done, I'm getting a connection error. Based on the url provided, have the correct arguments been passed to the connection?

Comment: I found the answer on server fault [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/475186/heroku-cleardb-mysql-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on server fault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/475186/heroku-cleardb-mysql-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)

The correct format for the database connection is:

```
$url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
$server = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$db = substr($url["path"], 1);
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);
```